# Is there any alternative way to install elixir/ Phoenix in windows 8

Tags: elixir

I can not install elixir in windows 8. Is there any alternative way to install elixir/ Phoenix in windows 8?

Comment: What issues do you have? What error message says? What have you tried? It’s extremely hard to suggest an alternative to unknown.

Comment: I download exe file  and try install exe file  this error is appeared   " Error:Downloading http://elixir-lang.org/elixier.csv failed . Setup cannot continue."

Comment: Where you download the file from? Also, update the question with the details.

Comment: .exe download the installer from this link(https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#windows) .
 I try to install  from .exe. That time show error . The setup not complete

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend it, but this can be useful if you having problem running the installer.

1. Go to https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases
2. Download `Precompiled.zip`
3. Extract `Precompiled.zip` to `c:\elixir`
4. Run `c:\elixir\bin\iex.bat` to see if it can run
5. Register `c:\elixir\bin` to your path